# php - nested array: access parent array scope when have only inner reference

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

Let's see the code:

```
function update_by_ref(&$ref)
{
    $ref[] = 2;
    $ref[] = 3;        
}

$a = [];
$a_ref = &$a;

$b = [];
$b[] = &$a_ref;

update_by_ref($a_ref);
print_r ($b);
```

Resulting array:

```
[[2,3]]
```

Is there any option to modify original array from within update_by_ref() function and obtain something like this:

```
[[2,3], [4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Child elements don't have information about parent scope, there might be no parent scope.